Get users from Microsoft Entra by API without Graph
I need to retrieve the list of users from Microsoft Entra by API.
I found this manual (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
There are others way to do that without Microsoft Graph?
Microsoft Graph is always included with Microsoft Entra?

Instead of Microsoft Graph, You can list the users with Azure Powershell or Azure CLI,
Refer this List Users

I need to retrieve the list of users from a web application, so I want to use API. I don't know if Graph is mandatory.

If you need to retrieve a list of users from Microsoft Entra ID via an API using web application, then using Microsoft Graph API is mandatory, It is an modern and unified API for accessing Microsoft services and it has replaced older API such Azure AD Graph API which has been deprecated

The Microsoft Graph API is the recommended and most comprehensive way to interact with data programmatically in Microsoft 365 which includes Microsoft Entra. This includes retrieving users and other directory data including groups, mail, messages, calendars, tasks, and notes, to name a few.To use Microsoft Graph, you have to set up the necessary authentication and permissions depending on the endpoint you are hitting.
Aside from retrieving users using Powershell as mentioned in the comments, you can manually download(as CSV) on the portal under Users but please note that this may take a while for tenants with a large number of users and thus the recommendation is to split the records processed per batch as defined in this documentation.
